# Cannot overload operator << because of singleton

Tags: c++, printing, singleton, operator-overloading

I followed this tutorial to create my singleton (my class is named King) : https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/2 ;
so here is my code :

King.h :

```
#include "Generic_Piece.h"

class King : public Generic_Piece {
public:
     //public static accessor function
     static King *instance();


 protected:
     //singleton : define all constructors to be protected
     King(){}

 private:
     static King *k;

 };

//Print the king in green colour
namespace std{
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const King& k);
}
```

King.cpp :

```
#include "King.h"

King *King::k = 0;
King *King::instance(){
    if(!k){
        k = new King();
        //the king is green
        k->setTeam(0);
    }
    return k;
}
//Printing the king
namespace std{
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const King& k){
        out << "\033[32m" << "K" << "\033[0m";
        return out;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my problem is that I want to overload the `<<` operator to print a green K. I call it like it in main :

```
std::cout << King::instance() << std::endl;
```

But it prints out the address `0x55d7a133f280`. I guess the problem is my use of the singleton. I guess I could print with a `King::print()` function, but I would really prefer to overload the `<<` operator. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `King::instance` returns a pointer, if you want to print the object you should dereference that pointer (actually that has nothing to do with singleton)

Comment: Singletons are an *anti*-pattern and mostly just glorified global variables. Likely to cause you much grief and pain. Just avoid them would be my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`King::instance` returns a pointer. Hence, when you write

```
std::cout << King::instance() << std::endl;
```

a different overload of `operator <<` is called - the one that takes `void*`. In order to print the instance using your operator, add a derererence:

```
std::cout << *King::instance() << std::endl;
```

Better yet, make `King::instance()` return a reference to `King`:

```
King& King::instance(){
    if(!k){
        k = new King();
        //the king is green
        k->setTeam(0);
    }
    return *k;
}
```

Now your original call of `operator <<` would produce the right results.

Comment: I can't believe it was so obvious. I was too focus on another part of the code, so I panicked. Thanks for you answer + improvement.